# Why some plants can be propagated from a leaf cutting but some can not?

Tags: botany

I understand the process of leaf-cutting propagation as following:

1) with the help of auxin from the leaf, callus is forming on the wound and then roots are forming from callus,

2) with the help of cytokinin from roots, shoots are forming.

Is it wrong or too simplified or do I miss something? Why some plants can do this and some can not?

Comment: Can we ever really know the plant cannot do this? All we can know is that combinations of conditions that have been tested did not work for that particular species/genotype.

Comment: You have a point. It seems like theoretically any plant can be propagated by leaf cutting in some specific conditions within some time. In this case are there any clearly identifiable characteristics of particular species/genotype that affect this ability, ceteris paribus? Or is it rather complex thing?

Comment: What I have seen people to do is mostly trying protocols that work for related species and trying large matrix of conditions on large set of genotypes etc. Once the protocol is established people seem to move on to using it instead of researching deeper reasons. If you find any overarching theoretical work on this matter I would be very much interested.

Comment: A major factor would be how fast a leaf dries out, A leaf that dries out quickly will not be able to keep photosynthesizing long enough to grow roots to collect more water.

Comment: The plant has to be able to develop meristems from the leaves, and plant stem cells for the roots?

Comment: @John it is necessary but not sufficient condition, isn't it? There is at least a problem of "blind" cutting: the cutting roots but does not produce any shoots to develop new full-fledged plant.

Comment: I have mostly experience with plant tissue culture on agarous media where drying of leaf is not problem. Still, some plants respond and some don't. Species I work with has been considered recalcitrant to in vitro for decades but then a different cytokinin molecule was tried and shoots started to form.